# Animate stokeRect opacity canvas

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

Basically, I just want to fade in an animation for a website I'm building.

```
drawRect: function(object) {
    var canvas = _site.vars.canvas;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    if (!context.setLineDash) {
        context.setLineDash = function() {}
    }
    context.setLineDash([5, 2]);
    context.strokeRect(object.x, object.y, object.w, object.h);
};
```

This is just one of the methods of my plugin, however this is the main code drawing my rectangles.

I basically have a loop that has a delay of 0.4s and constantly calls this function with new x,y,w,h params.

This all works great, however I'd really like to animate them in, rather than just make them appear.

I've been reading about this, but I can't really seem to find anything relevant.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great, the site I'm developing is [here](http://www.pixles.com.au).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an animation loop that fades in over 300ms (to accommodate your 400ms resizing rectangle):

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");


var x=50;
var y=50;
var w=100;
var h=75;

var startTime;

requestAnimationFrame(fadeIn);

$("#test").click(function(){
  startTime=null;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(fadeIn);    
});



function fadeIn(time){
  if(!startTime){startTime=time;}
  var elapsed=time-startTime;
  if(elapsed>300){
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
    return;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(fadeIn);
  ctx.globalAlpha=elapsed/300/1.50;
  ctx.clearRect(x-2,y-2,w+2,h+2);
  ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Rerun</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thankyou :)

Comment: Will this animate each box using this? Or will this animate all boxes?

Comment: It will flexibly do either. As designed it handles one example rect.  If you want to animate a bunch of rects then put each rect's x,y,w,h and it's startTime in an object and then put all those obejects in an array.  Process every array element inside the animation loop. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, I've done that but I have a few questions, they all animate in, but with very different end results, some end up at a higher alpha then others, why is that?

In the draw method, I have put the `requestAnimationFrame(fadeIn)` function in, I've replaced everything in that function with yours, but just settings a global variable for the object params.

I'm also setting the start time to 0 and the globalAlpha to 0 here.

Also why do you clear the rect?

Comment: Difficult to say without your code, but you'll have to keep the animation running until the last rect has faded in--that probably means keeping the animation running all the time (not really a problem). I forgot to mention in my comment that each rect object needs a `currentAlpha` value. The rects must be cleared each loop because multiple overwrites of semi-transparent strokes will accumulate. It's like applying multiple layers of paint so the stroke will darken much more quickly than required.

Comment: For some reason though, putting in the clearRect, makes the background of the strokerect non transparent? pixles.com.au

Comment: clearRect is required. Difficult to say where your glitch is without your code.  Here's an example fiddle showing how to deal with an array full of rects: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2Lr5aLao/  Good luck with your project!